# Springmvc @Scheduled cron or fixedrate not firing

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using all annotated version of springmvc and I have a class where I have scheduled a method to be run every 5 seconds. However, it doesnt seem to be firing.

I have created a package to be scanned when the app fires up and I have declared the class in the following way:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.iautomation")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

My class and cron:
@Component
public class DemoServiceBasicUsageCron {

```
//@Scheduled(cron="*/1 * * * * ?")
@Scheduled(fixedRate=5000)
public void demoServiceMethod()
{
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n");
    System.out.println("Method executed at every 5 seconds. Current time is :: ");
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n");
}
}
```

The package is scanned when the app starts:
DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'demoServiceBasicUsageCron'

and another debug log:
DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:86 - Rejected bean name 'demoServiceBasicUsageCron': no URL paths identified

When I load the app in eclipse I dont see anything in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to annotate your Configuration class with @EnableScheduling

Comment: Thank you JakubK. That was easy and its working now. I really appreciate this.